# Accessing SharePoint application online

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I didn't want to ask this twice (asked on ServerFault already, but see this maybe the best place to get this answered).

I am trying to access a Sharepoint application, but I have to input a /application to access.
For example, www.testsite.com/app.  This is actually for a client of mind.  I want the users to be able to go to just the domain itself without have to put a / then the application name to pull up the app.  I know in IIS it's called a default doc, but not sure where to change this setting in SharePoint.

Where I do go in Sharepoint to perform this task?

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

do it in iis:

```
http://mysite/sites/Department/IT/oldlist to

http://mysite/sites/Department/IT/newlist
```

> 1.On the filesystem in your webroot, create a folder structure mimicking the URL:
>
> c:inetpubsharepointrootsitesDepartmentIToldlist
>
> 2.Open IIS Management console and locate that folder
>
> 3.Right-click on that folder and select properties
>
> 4.Use the "A redirection to a URL" option in the Directory tab
>
> 5.Enter the new URL (absolute OR relative) in the Redirect To: box
>
> 6.Test it

http://jason.agostoni.net/2006/04/10/sharepoint-redirect-using-only-iis/

also another way:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/harmeetw/archive/2009/09/08/redirecting-a-sharepoint-subsite-or-a-site-collection-to-a-different-url.aspx

both ways should work for you for navigating from `http://mydomain` to `http://mydomain.com/app` quite easily

You can also do it this way!

1) goto 12 hive and copy the file sps404.html

2) change the code to this:

```
<!-- _localBinding -->
<!-- _lcid="1033" _version="" -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="0" /> 
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/_layouts/Custom404.aspx?noscript=1" />
    </noscript> 
    <script language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/core.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        var requestedUrl = escapeProperly(window.location.href);
        STSNavigate("/app.aspx);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

app.aspx is the url location for your application, if my site is hello.com it would be hello.com/app.aspx

3) enable publishing features by going to **Site Actions** -> **Site Settings** -> **Site Collection Features** -> and click on **Enterprise Publishing features**. now activate **SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure**

4) activate server publishing by going to **Site Actions** -> **Site Settings** -> **Manage Site Features** and click on **SharePoint Server Publishing**

5) upload the saved html file to sharepoint. Click on **site Actions** -> **View All Site Content** -> under document library click on **Style Library**. Once page is loaded you need to upload the page there by clicking on **Upload document** on the ribbon. Once the file is uploaded right click the file and select copy shortcut.

6) link up the page to the front page by clicking on **site Actions** -> **Site Settings**, under Look and Feel select **Welcome Page**. within the url textbox paste the copied url for the html file to redirect to the app page!

all done

now goto homepage and it should redirect to the app page ;)

another more complext way(if you dont know what your doing) is setting it in the dns record!

Answer (score 0):

The paths are actually managed by SharePoint.  AFAIK, there is no way to have a site collection respond to a path it is not on.  Your best bet would be to configure a 301 redirect from IIS to the relative path when someone tries to hit the root.

Not sure what version of SharePoint or IIS you are working with, but in the features section in IIS there should be an "HTTP Redirect" icon.  Follow the prompts in that feature to set it up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a web application in sharepoint then you can use alternate access mappings to direct a subdomain to your sharepoint site.  I'm not sure this is what you are talking about though.  If you mean you want a sub domain/domain to go to a specific site collection then you will have to setup an IIS application with a redirect and use host headers in IIS to tie it to that sub domain/domain.